# Recurring contributions not sending emails (Stripe)

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, stripe

I'm setting up a contribution page using the Stripe payment processor. In testing mode, one-off donations work fine in that they show up as expected in the test pane in the Stripe account, donations show up in CiviCRM, and also send the *Thank you* email specified in the Contribution page settings.

When I check the box to recur monthly, however, although everything else works as above, neither the initial email nor followup recurring payment emails are sent.

There is [an issue related to this in the Github queue](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/73) but it's kind of stagnant and was hoping someone here could give me a pointer on where to look to try to solve this.

(*CiviCRM version 4.6.3* with latest dev version of the CiviCRM-Stripe extension)

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem with WP 4.3 and CiviCRM 4.6.8, and the latest dev version of the extension. Is this specific to the Stripe extension, or are people seeing the same thing using other payment processors that support recurring payments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed now. If you get the latest version of the Stripe extension's code from Github, you will have email receipts for recurring contributions.

Answer (score 2):

[CRM-15629](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15629) produces similar symptoms with certain configurations of PayPal.  Also, please update your question with a CiviCRM version?