# Has anyone tried Stripe payments through OmniPay?

Tags: payment-processor, stripe, omnipay

The [Stripe payment processor extension](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe) works okay for the most part, but when there is an issue, [it seems hard to get any answers or feedback](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3284/recurring-contributions-not-sending-emails-stripe). I am curious if anyone has tried integrating Stripe payments through the [OmniPay extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/omnipay-multiprocessor-extension), and if so how that went?

Comment: Yes, I think if you could highlight the issues you've been having that might also help. We've done quite a bit of work on the stripe extension recently and are pushing a few code changes back to the maintainers. If you could share your issues we might be able to confirm if they're being addressed.

Answer (score 2):

I think Stripe through the Omnipay extension is not working at the moment. We are looking into Stripe as well and will wait for the regular extension to be updated like Parvez mentioned.