# Stripe and CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, stripe

I am evaluating Stripe and was wondering if CiviCRM 4.7.6/Drupal support Stripe?
Stripe has two ways of integration, the 'Embedded payment form' (Stripe Checkout) and a 'Custom payment form' (Stripe.Js), are both these methods supported by CiviCRM <>Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this extension: [Stripe Payment Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/stripe-payment-processor)?

I haven't used it myself so perhaps others can comment on how well it works.

There is also this related post: [Has anyone tried Stripe payments through OmniPay?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/has-anyone-tried-stripe-payments-through-omnipay?rq=1)

Comment: We've used stripe through WP for years using the extension. Drupal shouldn't be a problem. Not sure the technical side...

Comment: I use Stripe without issue on civi4.7/Drupal 7